# why is : fp_len = 400 , size_t len = 1

Tags: c

determine content-length and append '\0'

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long fp_len;
fp_len = ftell(fp); 
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *text = malloc(sizeof(*text) * fp_len + 1);
size_t len = fread(text, fp_len, 1, fp);

text[fp_len] = '\0';
```

fp_len prints : 400, while len prints : 1

```
printf("%d", fp_len);
printf("%d", len);
```

my understanding is this is wrong:

```
text[fp_len] = '\0';
```

and this is correct :

```
text[len] = '\0';
```

but if "len" is printing 1..

wouldn't '\0' be added to the 2nd spot in the array ?

Comment: You ask [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) to read ***one*** block of length `fp_len`. That's the `1` that is returned.

Comment: Second question today on the exact same code snippet...hmmm...

Comment: Save time.  Turn on compiler warnings to see a problem with `printf("%d", len);` and others.

Comment: `fread` returns number of elements read. `fread(text, fp_len, 1, fp)` --> `fread(text, 1, fp_len, fp)`

Comment: `gcc -Wall` : no warnings.

Comment: so how will it know how to append the null character ?

Comment: Why do you think `text[fp_len]='\0'` is wrong?

Comment: because it is said.. the bytes read may not be same as content-length which is "characters. not bytes."

Comment: `-Wformat` warns about `printf("%d", fp_len);`

Comment: I assume you are working with text, since you allocate an extra byte for a string terminator. Although `fread` can be used to read the entire file into memory for processing, `fread` is more often used with binary data, not text. With a text file, it is more usual to read and examine each text line, and a better function for this is `fgets`.

Comment: `gcc -Wformat`  no warnings.

Comment: *"because it is said.. the bytes read may not be same as content-length"* but you just **asked** it the file length. The usual way to use `fread` is to read the file in chunks until no bytes were read, and that is the customary use of the return value.

Comment: @WeatherVane `ftell(fp);` does not need to report the file length found by reading a text file with `fread()`.  `"abc\r\n"` may have an `ftell()` result of 5, yet `fread()` result of 4.

Comment: @chux that's true, but (I assume) the file was opened in binary mode, so EOL conversions are not performed. `fread` does not do those conversions anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP's code/comments do not indicate the mode in which `fp` was opened.  May be binary, may be text.  `fread()` does do those conversions in text mode.  Posts that lack such info are less useful than post that do.

Comment: @chux mybad, the man page does say that.

Comment: @JohnBode it's our "cgi troll"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `fread(text, fp_len, 1, fp)` asks to read one element of size `fp_len` so after succesful execution result is `1` (number of elements read) or it can be `0` if reading fails.

If you want to count number of bytes (character) read from file, you can change places of arguments, like

```
 fread(text, 1, fp_len, fp)
```

For more information refer to [references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)

Answer (score 1):

> size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * restrict stream);

As other have said, `fread` returned 1 - the number of elements read and each had a size of `size` or 400.

Put the augments in the correct order.

```
// size_t len = fread(text, fp_len, 1, fp);
size_t len = fread(text, 1, fp_len, fp);
```

---

Better to avoid magic numbers like 1 here.  Instead, use the size of the `text[]` element.

```
size_t len = fread(text, sizeof *text, fp_len, fp);
```

Further, code lacks error checking and `printf()` specifier correctness.

```
if (fp == NULL) Handle_Error("fopen");
if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)) Handle_Error("fseek");
long fp_len = ftell(fp); 
if (fp_len == -1) Handle_Error("ftell");
if (fp_len < 0 || fp_len >= SIZE_MAX) Handle_Error("long to size_t");

char *text = malloc(sizeof *text * (fp_len + 1));
if (text == NULL)  Handle_Error("malloc");
size_t len = fread(text, 1, fp_len, fp);
if (len == 0 && fp_len > 0) Handle_Error("fread");
text[len] = '\0';

printf("%ld", fp_len); // note specifiers
printf("%zu", len);
```

Comment: Upvote for error-handling and conversion specifier corrections.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) you need to write

```
fread(text, 1, fp_len, fp);
```